# How do I find (quickly - 15-20ms) LatLong for an Address using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, google-geocoder

I have a socket.io which pings a new Address every 15-20ms. For this Address, I have to get the Lat-Long and place the marker in Google Maps. So within those 15-20ms (if not, may be within 50-60ms) I have to get the GeoLocation. Currently I am using `geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();` and then `geocoder.geocode({address: data}, myFunction(){});`

But this API for Maps is very slow. It returns GeoLocation in 400-500ms which renders my intermediate Address requests null. I need an API which is very fast.

For reference, below is the code snippet for socket.io:

```
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
    socket.on('new_address', function (data) {
        //Gets called everytime a new request for GeoLocation comes
        geocoder.geocode({address: data}, placeMarker);
    });

var placeMarker = function(){
    //Add Marker to GoogleMaps
};
```

Comment: Even your network latency will exceed 15-20ms. I can't see any way to do this unless you can perform reverse geocoding using some local database.

Comment: try and ask google to buy more network and faster servers ^^

Comment: Why don't you call the Google API from your server (central) and deliver the address along with the lat/lon-data?

Comment: @ Cthulhu..It may happen the network latency exceeds the time. But it will surely be not as high as 400-500ms. Yes, the other way is that to maintain a local database, but I was hoping if any other API is available to fill the need.

@ Bergi..I think I can do that but again the Google API will take its time to return the LatLong. It will cause the same latency problem on the server side socket.io.

Comment: @tanmaykhandelwal: No, since your server probably (hopefully?) has a better network connectivity than the client. Also, as far as I can see your problem is the time between socket handler and `placeMarker` (for some UX reasons?) and that would be zero if you "delayed" the socket message and sent both info at once.

Comment: @Bergi: Ok. The server probably be fast. And yes you are right the main constrain is time. But another thing is that i cannot delay the ping from the socket. Essentially the ping represents some call to some server which is of that order only. The server serves requests at that high speed.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you can't actually expect a response within 20ms on the internet, it just doesn't work that way. What you cán however do is making a sort of pool with the addresses and let the geocoder (or maybe 3 of 4) work on it on it's own pace.

This would probably look somewhat like this (just giving a direction here, don't expect it to work right away):

```
var addresses = [];
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
socket.on('new_address', function (data) {
    //Gets called everytime a new request for GeoLocation comes
    //Adds an address to the list when it comes in from the backend
    adresses.push(data);
});

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
//This function is called in a loop.
var addressCheck = function() {
    //When the list of addresses is empty, because we haven't received anything from the backend, just wait for a bit and call this function again.
    if(addresses.length == 0) {
        setTimeout(addressCheck, 400);
        return;
    }
    //Get the first one on the list.
    var data = addresses[0];
    //Process it.
    geocoder.geocode({address: data}, function() {
        placeMarker();
            //remove the first element from the adresses list.
        addresses.shift();
            //Call the entire function again, so it starts with a new address.
        addressCheck();
    });
}
var placeMarker = function(){
    //Add Marker to GoogleMaps
};

addressCheck();
```

Comment: huh? How would that independent interval shorten the time from the socket handler to calling `placeMarker`? Also, this script will not work if the geocoder takes more than 400ms to compute a result.

Comment: It doesn't work like that... The idea is that the javascript gets the addresses from node/socket.io and a separate function addressCheck is called in a loop to process it. The callback of the geocoder calls the function again to restart it. The 400ms-delay is there to give the browser some slack when there are no more addresses on the list.

Comment: Oh, right, I misunderstood the loop. Still, using a separate function won't make the geocoder faster. With your interval, in the worst case the time from `adresses.push` to `placeMarker` could double up.

Comment: The answer is simple: You can't lookup in that short of time, you've all said that. I am showing a way to fix the problem: He gets addresses from socket.io and wants markers on a map to show. The time is irrelevant, when the requests work.

Comment: Fix which problem? The OPs sample code works. He asked about time improvements.

Comment: I am quoting from the OP: "But this API for Maps is very slow. It returns GeoLocation in 400-500ms which renders my intermediate Address requests null."

Comment: @JacoKoster: Bergi is right. The main question is time improvement. I can store data in an array but that doesn't help me getting the response faster from the google maps API. The requirement is of a fast response of LatLong values corresponding to an address.

Comment: Well, in that case, there is not much to recommend. Good luck finding a solution!